# How to extract files from a Time Capsule backup hard drive?

Tags: mac, backup

Since my old Apple Time Capsule from 2012 stopped working, I was intending to throw it out, so I removed the hard drive, and was intending to recover the data from my backups, by just copying it from the hard drive, like I can with a normal Time Machine backup to a normal drive.

However, the backups appear to be compressed or split up in some way. When I open the main partition of the drive on my Windows computer, which I do with a HFS driver installed to read the mac file system, I find a folder called "ShareRoot". In this folder, I find a folder with my Mac's name, with the extension `.sparsebundle`. In this folder, I find various files, including a folder called "bands", which appears to contain all the data. However, the data appears to be split of into lots and lots of file, all with two or three character names, with no extension, and with a size of exactly 8192 KB.

So, what do I do from here? How can I get my data from these files? I would prefer to do it on Windows, but I can use a Mac if there's no way to do it on Windows. I've tried HFS Explorer, but I can't use it, because I'm blind and it doesn't work with my screen reader at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sparse bundle is a kind of Mac disk image. If you access it from a Mac and double-click on it in the Finder, macOS's built in disk image handling will mount it as a virtual disk.

You can also use the Disk Utility app to verify and mount it, or the command-line `hdiutil`.

I doubt anyone has ever bothered to create sparse bundle handling software for Windows, so I strongly suspect you'll need a Mac for this.

Comment: I've actually tried that since I wrote the question, on two different macs, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click on it, or press command+o. I've also tried to restore it to another harddrive, but also without success. I have two different bundles from two different macs, but neither of them work, so I don't think the image is corupted.

Comment: @akse0435 I updated my Answer. See if Disk Utility or hdiutil can give you more information on what's wrong with your sparsebundle.